# In Magento, can I add a static block to the header by xml only?

Tags: magento

I am trying to customize a theme using only local.xml whenever possible. I want to add a static block to the header without modifying header.phtml. This code works fine for the content area, but not for the header:

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="how-it-works-button">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>how-it-works</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Anybody know why? I thought that all I would need is to change “content” to “header”, but nothing shows up when I do.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The `content` block is a special block known as a `core/text_list` block (PHP class `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`).  These blocks will automatically render out any child blocks that are added to them.

The `header` block, on the other hand, is a `page/html_header` block (PHP class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header`).  This block class inherits from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, making it a `core/template` block.  Template blocks will **only** render sub-blocks if their corresponding `phtml` template requests the block.  So, by adding your block to the header, you're only doing half the work you need to.  **You'll need to create a custom `phtml` template**.

The simplest way to do this (post `1.4.1.1` is to, in your own theme, create a file at

```
template/page/html/header.phtml
```

And then at the end of this file add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('how-it-works-button'); ?>
```

Assuming you've added a block to header block via layout xml, this should render your template.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this now. As another comment suggested, I tried adding output="toHtml" to the block, but this only cause the content to appear at the extreme bottom of the page. I now see that this is because Magento has no template to anchor the html to. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('how-it-works')->toHtml() ?>
```

> And this code in `header.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

add output="toHtml" in the block tag. I think it is only that.

Comment: This is just the kind of thing I was looking for. However, when I used it, the static block appears at the bottom of the page, below even the footer. Alan Storm's comment makes it clear to me why this is, but thank you for the useful experiment!