# How do I add inline css in Magentocommerce page from admin?

Tags: css, magento, layout

I just want to add

```
<style type="text/css>
 my_inline_style...
</style>
```

In one page. I know I can add things like this from Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action name="addCss"><stylesheet>externalCss.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

But where is it documented to write inline css from that area?

Comment: Technically I think you could use a static block to store your css that append the static block to your layout content see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946482/in-magento-can-i-add-a-static-block-to-the-header-by-xml-only

Comment: Can you clarify: why would you write inline style? And not just adding CSS for that certain page via XML?

Comment: Because the store owner understands css, but would prefer not to update via ftp. Valid enough a reason?

Comment: The point of CSS is to separate the content (HTML) from the presentation (CSS). It's all about accessibility and code reuse. Problem with inline styleing is its difficult to maintain and you have to look for every instance when making a change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar situation and arrive at this solution. That is not elegant but is useful (you can add any text throw layout update).
Add something like this to the layout update:

```
<reference name="head">
   <block type="core/text" name="custom_css">
      <action method="setText">
          <text><![CDATA[
             <style  type="text/css">
                .my-class  {
                    color: red;
                }
             </style> ]]>
        </text>
    </action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Btw, It is hard to add the CSS style inline into the cms blocks because is hidden by some process inside the WYSIWYG editor after you save the block.